# Function textFieldShouldBeginEditing is not called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview, uitextfielddelegate

I know that there are similar questions, but thiere answers didn't help me. I geuss I have some other bug.

I have a textView, I am setting it's delegate to self, but the relevant function is not called.

Here is the code:

In .h:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
```

In .m:

```
...
@synthesize nameField;
...
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    nameField.delegate = self;
...
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    exitKeyboardButton.hidden = NO;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have connected the `nameField` outlet in Interface Builder?

Comment: You work correct, it was not connected, but it didn't help. It is still not responding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I used relevant IBAction functions.
I you have a better idea, let me know, I will mark you answer.

[image]

Comment: You dont need to set the top connections, once the delegate has been set either programmatically or via the nib all the callbacks are inherently called. For example a TableViewDelegate calls cellForRow, numberOfRows etc. You never have to

Answer (score 6):

I suppose you forget wire the delegate of text field to your viewController. I often forget : )

[image: ss]

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

Set the delegate (but as idz said, there are problem with this) in `viewDidLoad` not `viewWillAppear`

Try `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` instead of `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`

Make extra extra extra sure you have the right name connected in the nib